# Why can't I get the total row count for my grid field?

Tags: ee2, grid, 2.8

I have a Grid field (called 'beneficiaries') that I'm using to hold a list of first names and last names of beneficiaries, but I'm struggling to get a template to output the total number of rows my Grid field's currently holding. I'm able to output the entire field with the currently submitted data, using:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="beneficiary" return="/next_page" entry_id="8"}
    {beneficiaries}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

And that works great.

Now I just want to print to the screen the total number of rows, much like:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="beneficiary" return="/next_page" entry_id="8"}
    Total: {beneficiaries:total_rows}<br />
    Total: {beneficiaries:field_total_rows}<br />
    Total: {field:beneficiaries:total_rows}<br />
    Total: {field:beneficiaries:field_total_rows}<br />
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Which only returns the following:

```
Total: {beneficiaries:total_rows}
Total: {beneficiaries:field_total_rows}
Total:
Total:
```

Am I doing something painfully obviously wrong? I've read and re-read [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html) to no avail, and I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Any help as to why I can't seem to display the row count would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid field is a looping field, so if the field is in fact called beneficiaries, you should have:

```
{beneficiaries}
  {beneficiaries:total_rows}
  {beneficiaries:field_total_rows}
{/beneficiaries}
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html#id5

You can find the total rows outside the looping pair

Comment: I hadn't realized that. Is that be the case within a channel form too?

Comment: @JohnathanWaters - I've tried that with no success unfortunately :( See my OP...unless I've missed something?

Comment: @JeanSt-Amand Thanks for this! I would've liked to get this outside of the looping pair as it would be convenient to display other content depending on how many rows have been added...sigh!